# HTML form on Azure storage account with Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, web-development-server

Using Azure table storage to store user, unique user code and associated card number

Looking to create an html form (stored in Azure Storage account) where user can enter their code and when submitting the form, Azure functions should get triggerred which can lookup for the user name in Azure table and provide a confirmation on the form saying "Welcome Samuels".

After this, the transaction should be stored back in Azure table and an SMS should be triggered from Azure functions.

I don't know how to accomplish this. Please help on how to achieve it.

Comment: Will you be using same storage account for your HTML form and the table containing data?

Comment: yes. Same storage account. Looking to use Python in Azure function.

Comment: Thanks. Are you looking for sample code or an approach to solve this problem?

Comment: if I get sample code, that'll be fine.. But if someone can guide me on which path to follow, i can learn myself and implement that